# (C shell) How i use environment variables in foreach loop condition

Tags: linux, csh

I want to generate the loop with reading files

In my directory, There are many files.

So, i tried below

```
setenv sel $1

foreach file (`cat ./$sel`)
  ...
end
```

But, It didn't work and I think foreach loop can't read '$sel'.
How do i do?

Comment: Can you be more precise than *"it didn't work"*? What are you passing as `$1`? What are you expecting to happen, and what happens, exactly?